# How to secure videos from being downloaded

Tags: video, file-security

so I'm creating karaoke website for client, and I need to secure videos from beign downloaded. So for example he is able to put in flash videos, how can I make sure noone can download them, cause it will be internet shop, where people will be able to buy the song and play it for like 1 hour, after that it won't be able, but the issue is that if they will buy it for one hour, they will be able to download it and play it as long as they want. You got any suggestions?

Comment: If you can see it, you can copy it.  I you can watch and hear it, you can record it.  Sorry, that is the nature of the beast.

Comment: My 0.02: With plugins all over the place capturing the stream, that's a difficult task.

Comment: Should this be considered a Frequently Asked Question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a waste of time: anything that reaches the users machine can be captured and saved.

Your client will not understand this, of course, so you may have to demonstrate using a program like Total Recorder.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no way out of here.. even if you use Flash Media Server the stream can be captured and saved by any recording software

Answer (score 0):

Sites like Deezer are wondering how, but they haven't found any really working solution yet.

If you can see it, you can download it, that's the game !

Answer (score 0):

you may use Streaming Video Servers  like Amazon CloudFront CDN so no one can download your video